# Please help me understand why a sub-query affects the main query's use of index

Tags: sql, mysql

Here is the main query without a sub-query:

```
SELECT * FROM 
    mytable AS idx
WHERE 
    idx.ID IN (1,2,3) 
    AND idx.P1 = 'galleries';
```

The index on this table is **id_path (ID,P1)**

Everything is fine at this point, the index is used, 3 rows are examined and 2 are returned. Without the index 9 rows would have to be examined.

Now if i replace the list of IDs with a sub-query that returns exactly the same set of IDs, 
the main query still returns the correct rows, but it stops using the index and does an examination of 9 rows as if the index never even existed.

```
SELECT * FROM 
    mytable AS idx
WHERE 
    idx.ID IN (SELECT idxrev.ID FROM mytable AS idxrev WHERE idxrev.ID IN (1,2,3)) 
    AND idx.P1 = 'galleries';
```

My question is, why does this happen and what could i do to make the main query use the index as before. I tried adding **USE INDEX (id_path)** but that just made it even worse, doing a whole table scan.

Comment: @gbn: `USE INDEX` is only supported by `MySQL`.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable AS idx
WHERE   idx.ID IN
        (
        SELECT  idxrev.ID
        FROM    mytable AS idxrev
        WHERE   idxrev.ID IN (1,2,3)
        ) 
        AND idx.P1 = 'galleries'
```

`MySQL`'s only way to make semi-joins is nested loops.

It needs to take every row of `idx` and check it against `idxrev` (using the indexes for that).

Of course a better method in this case would be a `HASH SEMI JOIN` or just reducing your query to the original one, but `MySQL` is just not capable of it.

To make the query use the index, just revert to your original query :)

Comment: Perhaps using two separate queries is not so bad. The sub-query will almost always return fewer rows than the main query given the same input.

Comment: @Stephanie: how can this subquery return fewer rows if its conditions are more permissive than those of the original query? This subquery will return more or the same amount of rows as the original query.

Answer (score 0):

That's one of the great mysteries of MySQL; it doesn't cope well with subqueries. You could try to change the **IN** to an **EXISTS** which is sometimes faster. It looks a bit silly in this example because you still use the hardcoded list, but I think thats just for testing, right?

```
SELECT * FROM 
    mytable AS idx
WHERE 
    idx.ID EXISTS 
        (SELECT idxrev.ID 
        FROM mytable AS idxrev 
        WHERE 
           idxrev.ID = idx.ID AND
           idxrev.ID IN (1,2,3)) 
    AND idx.P1 = 'galleries';
```

If this doesn't help, maybe you could run two queries. First you get all the ids an put them in a comma separated list (using GROUP_CONCAT if you like). Then you build the second query by using that value.

Comment: Indeed, the hardcoded 1,2,3 is just for testing. This is a bridge table to flatten the hierarchy of my main content table. It contains the path for every row in the main table in a forward and reverse direction. The sub-query comes into effect when for looking up a path like "galleries//lolcat". It would return every row where P1 = "lolcat" and Reverse = 1 (which i left out of my example). The main query would take care of matching P1 = "galleries" and Reverse = 0 and the IDs returned from the sub-query.